# Add New Row in GridView cannot find reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an editable `GridView` but I would also like to have an add new row functionality, so I made a button using `FooterTemplate` for all editable fields and set `CommandName="AddNew"` . Everything looks as expected on the front end, but Add New Row cannot find `txtGrantId`, `txtPotId` or `txtBudget` at all and throws `System.NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`. The issue has to be in the code behind, but I am attaching the front end as well. The data source is pretty long but it does call `OnRowCommand="gvPotsMoneyGrants_RowCommand"`

ASPX

```
<%--Primary Key LinkId--%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LinkId" SortExpression="LinkId">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblLinkId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LinkId") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

<%--GrantId--%>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GrantId" SortExpression="GrantId">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGrantIdMain" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("GrantId") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrantId" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("GrantId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="inGrantId" Width="120px" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vGrantId" runat="server" ControlToValidate="inGrantId" Text="?" ValidationGroup="VG5" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<%--PotId--%>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PotId" SortExpression="PotId">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPotIdMain" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PotId") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPotId" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("PotId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="inPotId" Width="120px" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vPotId" runat="server" ControlToValidate="inPotId" Text="?" ValidationGroup="VG5" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<%--Budget--%>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Budget" SortExpression="Budget">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblBudgetMain" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Budget") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBudget" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Budget") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="inBudget" Width="120px" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vBudget" runat="server" ControlToValidate="inBudget" Text="?" ValidationGroup="VG5" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind

```
 protected void gvPotsMoneyGrants_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
        {
            TextBox txtGrantId = (TextBox)gvPotsMoneyGrants.FooterRow.FindControl("txtGrantId");
            TextBox txtPotId = (TextBox)gvPotsMoneyGrants.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPotId");
            TextBox txtBudget = (TextBox)gvPotsMoneyGrants.FooterRow.FindControl("txtBudget");
        string GrantId, PotId, Budget;

        GrantId = txtGrantId.Text;
        PotId = txtPotId.Text;
        Budget = txtBudget.Text;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GrantId", GrantId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PotId", PotId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Budget", Budget);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the code below.

```
protected void gvPotsMoneyGrants_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
    {
        TextBox inGrantId = (TextBox)gvPotsMoneyGrants.FooterRow.FindControl("inGrantId");
        TextBox inPotId = (TextBox)gvPotsMoneyGrants.FooterRow.FindControl("inPotId");
        TextBox inBudget = (TextBox)gvPotsMoneyGrants.FooterRow.FindControl("inBudget");
    string GrantId, PotId, Budget;

    GrantId = inGrantId.Text;
    PotId = inPotId.Text;
    Budget = inBudget.Text;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GrantId", GrantId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PotId", PotId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Budget", Budget);

    }
}
```

Comment: I missed the html element, it had to be inBudget and etc. Thank you so much for pointing it out!